# Не получается вызвать массив объектов GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Есть функция запроса, которая должна возвращать массив объектов, такого содержания:

```
Messages [{
    id: 16,
    message: 'rgrgegergerg',
    sender_name: 'gfregrgrg',
    sender_id: '1',
    send_date: 2021-04-21T04:33:13.285Z
  },
  Messages {
    id: 15,
    message: 'ergvergreg',
    sender_name: 'gfregrgrg',
    sender_id: '1',
    send_date: 2021-04-21T04:33:10.551Z
  },
  Messages {
    id: 14,
    message: 'gergrege',
    sender_name: 'gfregrgrg',
    sender_id: '1',
    send_date: 2021-04-21T04:33:09.430Z
  }
]
```

Этот массив возвращает функция initializeMessages:

```
@Query(() => MessageModel, { name: 'initializeMessages' })
  async initializeMessages() {
    return await this.messagesService.initializeMessages().then((result) => {
      return result;
    });
  }
```

Ожидается возврат по такой модели (нулябельность стоит временно):

```
@ObjectType()
export class MessageModel {
  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  id?: number;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  message!: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  sender_name!: string;

  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  sender_id?: number;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  send_date?: string;

  @Field(() => [MessagesModel])
  messages: MessagesModel[];
}
```

Модель массива:

```
@ObjectType()
export class MessagesModel {
  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  id?: number;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  message!: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  sender_name!: string;

  @Field(() => Int, { nullable: true })
  sender_id?: number;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  send_date?: string;
}
```

Пытаюсь сделать такой запрос через подсказки графа, но выбивает ошибку синтаксиса:

```
query kavo {
              initializeMessages {
                messages{...}
              }
          }
```

[image: Ошибка синтаксиса]

Подскажите как правильно сделать запрос в моем случае.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Убрал в модели это:

```
@Field(() => [MessagesModel])
  messages: MessagesModel[];
```

И изменил запрос:

```
@Query(() => MessageModel
```

На:

```
@Query(() => [MessageModel]
```

Кто же знал, что здесь массив определяется не в конце по стандарту.